# How to get accurate data from api in my case?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have api with specific construction and I need to get receive user-specific data.

In the Rates pojo I have the eUR and gBP fields and of course I need to set one of them if I want to get accurate currency rate data.
As you can see in the last lines of my code I have: 
Rates rate = data.getValue().getRates();
and in this case I don't get rate data, but if I set getEUR for example I have exact what I need. So how in my case set the code or even rebuild code to have opportunity to choose currency in the spinner in my view?

```
public class Currency {

@SerializedName("base")
@Expose
private String base;
@SerializedName("last_update")
@Expose
private String lastUpdate;
@SerializedName("rates")
@Expose
private Rates rates;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private int status;
@SerializedName("target")
@Expose
private String target;

public String getBase() {
    return base;
}

public void setBase(String base) {
    this.base = base;
}

public String getLastUpdate() {
    return lastUpdate;
}

public void setLastUpdate(String lastUpdate) {
    this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
}

public Rates getRates() {
    return rates;
}

public void setRates(Rates rates) {
    this.rates = rates;
}

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getTarget() {
    return target;
}

public void setTarget(String target) {
    this.target = target;
}



public class Rates {

@SerializedName("EUR")
@Expose
private double eUR;
@SerializedName("GBP")
@Expose
private double gBP;

public double getEUR() {
    return eUR;
}

public void setEUR(double eUR) {
    this.eUR = eUR;
}

public double getGBP() {
    return gBP;
}

public void setGBP(double gBP) {
    this.gBP = gBP;
}



 Rates rate = data.getValue().getRates();
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(rate));
```

JSON:

```
{
"base": "USD",
"last_update": "2018-12-10T15:10:58.253Z",
"rates": {
    "EUR": 0.8769574627,
    "GBP": 0.7914459201
    },
"status": 200,
"target": "EUR,GBP"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parce Json rates object with **Map** instead of Rate object. Get spinner values by using **map.keyset()** method

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what your problem is.
You have something in the app that determines which rate to use, right? You mentioned a spinner?  So why would it not just be a matter of calling either the `getEUR()` or the `getGBP()` based on that?

So something very simple like

```
Rates rates = data.getValue().getRates();
double rate;
if (eur) {   // or whatever logic you need to decide which rate to choose
   rate = rates.getEUR();
} else {
   rate = rates.getGBP();
}
```

Comment: So I have two spinners. In that spinners are several currencies. For example if I want to check how euro is worth to British pound, in first one I set EUR and in second one GBP. But if I want to take rate I have to use that kind of code:
Rates rates = data.getValue().getRates().getEUR;
But what I want different currency rate? 
I used your idea and in stack trace I have this: com.example.daniellachacz.currencyconverter2.data.model.Rates@2038aa